# Get Data from text and plot on Highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, text, highcharts

I have text file with data in the following manner

PC.json

[{"Category_B":[2, 0.5, 2.5], "numpoints":[3.2, 4.5, 0.5], "windspeed":[.5, 5.1, .1],
"power":[0.0, 2.5, 3.2]}, {"Category_B":[3, 1.5, 2], "numpoints":[1.2, 2.5, 0.5], "windspeed":[1.5, 4.1, 2.1],"power":[0.5, 2.5, 3.2]},{"Category_B":[1, 2.5,1], "numpoints":[2.2, 3.5, 1.5], "windspeed":[1.5, 3.1, 2.5],"power":[4.5, 5.5, 3.5]},
{"Category_B":[3, 1.5, 2], "numpoints":[1.2, 2.5, 0.5], "windspeed":[1.5, 4.1, 2.1],
"power":[0.5, 1.5, 2.2]}

.....

....]

this is jquery code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 155
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Power',
            x: -20 //center
        },


        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Kh'
            }

        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y;
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: []
    }


     $.getJSON("PC.json", function(json) 
    {

      var len = json.length
     var i=0;
        for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        var x= "POWER";
        var y= json[i]['power'];

            if(i==0){
                options.xAxis.categories = x;
            }else{
                 alert("X==== " + x + " and Y==== " + y); //able to get the power values
               // j = i-1;
                options.series[i] = y;
            }
     }

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

});
```

How do i get power values and windspeed values and plot it for 2 line charts in highcharts?

Comment: Please post what you've tried already.

Answer (score 1):

Txt file is not a JSON, so that will not work properly, could you return your file return rom you back-end as json / js / csv / xml ?

Comment: yes i have changed to .json file and able to get the values in alert but not able to plot it...

Comment: it just shows a horizontal line with label and at the right it shows series1, series2,....

Comment: any solution for the above?

Comment: how to add to series and plot?